# Find Replace In Word 2000

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

How can I do a find and replace using C# in a word doc?  For example, let's replace all instances of the word "Run" with "Ran"?

Maybe something like a String.Replace("run", "ran"); but that executed okay, but no changes were made.

Comment: Could you post the code where you tried that?

Comment: Why Word 2000? Office 2000 does not support Managed add-ins, unless you're using the Office COM API from within your own process?

Comment: also, Word 2000 has not been in active or extended support since July 14, 2009, so it's unlikely that it would be compatible with newer C# constructs.

Comment: I am running a mail merge and once the mail merge is finished I am wanting to find and replace.  This is not an add-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Find and Replace method :

```
public void FindAndReplaceWordText(ref Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc, string textToReplace, string newText)
{
    object missing = System.Type.Missing;

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range tmpRange in wordDoc.StoryRanges)
    {
        //set the text to find and replace
        tmpRange.Find.Text = textToReplace;
        tmpRange.Find.Replacement.Text = newText;

        tmpRange.Find.Wrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;

        //Declare an object to pass as a parameter that sets the Replace parameter to the "wdReplaceOne" enum.
        object replaceOne = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceOne;
        //Execute the Find and Replace
        tmpRange.Find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                              ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                              ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceOne,
                              ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
```

Invoking the method:

```
FindAndReplaceWordText(ref wordDoc, "Ran", "Run");
```

Hope this helps!